# why my servlet execute so many update at the end of my request?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, servlets, struts-1

I have an application with struts, spring and hibernate. For each request we open a transaction. But I have a behavior that i don't understand.
I want to charge a list of person, so i do a request on the database (db2) with a result of 10 rows. I put them in a List and I put this list in the request and i that's all (I don't modify the objects). 
When the jsp page is open and totalyy charge, the servlet launch 10 updates. one for each elements of my list but i don't understand why. 
We use PointcutFilter in the app, and call the method doFilter.

Can you explain why I have update request on the database ?

web.xml

```
<filter>
<filter-name>pointcutFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
!-- Permet d'ouvrir une transaction pour chaque requête -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>pointcutFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/action/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

dataAccessContext.xml (hibernate)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- similarly, don't forget the PlatformTransactionManager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pointcutFilter" class="fr.edu.nancy.commun.web.filters.PointcutFilter"/>

    <!-- Configuration du tissage d'aspect transactionnel. -->
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="managerOperationCommun" expression="execution(* fr.edu.nancy.commun.service..*.*(..))" />
        <aop:pointcut id="wrappingTransaction" expression="execution(* fr.edu.nancy.commun.web.filters..*.*(..))" />

        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdviceManagerOperationCommun" pointcut-ref="managerOperationCommun" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdviceManagerOperationCommun" pointcut-ref="wrappingTransaction" />
    </aop:config>

    <!-- Configuration transactionnelle générale (gestionnaires et DAO) -->
    <tx:advice id="txAdviceManagerOperationCommun" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="doFilter" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" read-only="false"
                rollback-for="RuntimeException,ApplicationException" />

            <tx:method name="*" propagation="SUPPORTS" read-only="true"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
</beans>
```

Action.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected ActionForward doExecute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm inputForm, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ApplicationException {

        // on s'assure que la liste ne sera pas paginée
        getInfoListe().setPaginationSupport(null);

        List<Person> employes = personneManager.listerEmployes(this.<Person> getInfoListe());
        request.setAttribute("employes", employes);

        String codeDeptMen = getProfilUtilisateur().getAccesCourant().getValCtx();

        // état applicatif du département est Saisie ?
        if (appAutomateManager.isEtatFonctionnelDepartement(codeDeptMen, AppAutomateManager.ETAT_DEPT_SAISIE,
                false)) {
            request.setAttribute("etatSaisie", true);
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("etatSaisie", false);
            addMessageWarning("warning.dossier.modificationInterditeDirecteursHorsSaisie");
        }

        // forward vers l'affichage de la liste des formations
        return mapping.findForward(AF_SUCCESS);
    }
```

Comment: It is better ta add some code.

Comment: I put a part of the code. I hope it will help

Comment: nobody can help please ??? I can put more code if necessary

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I don't know how to explain my problem. It's difficult to put an example because the problem comes from the pointcut filter in spring. At the end of the transaction, the program sent automatically update request on the db for the list I want to display. I think the list is in the hibernate session but I don't modify any attributes of the list so I don't undestand why the data have to be persist.